# "PDO_Construct: Unknown databasename" error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Experts,

This is got to be the most frustrating experience of my coding life.

I am just trying to connect to my DB using `PDO`.

I am doing it successfully with `mysqli` but with `PDO`, I am getting the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'myDBName,host=localhost'' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\closures\forms\final.php:51 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\closures\forms\final.php(51):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=di...', 'myusername', 'mypassword',
>   Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\closures\forms\final.php on
>   line 51

I changed db name for security.

Here is connection string:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=myDBname,host=localhost","mysusername","mypass",array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
```

This worked perfectly using msqli:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","myusername","mypass","myDB"); but I am using PDO because I am using PDO because it allows me to use array but because of this error, I am unable to test to see if my array works.
```

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php and don't intermix any other mysql api if that's what you're doing also. You left out something here btw. Example from the manual `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);`

Comment: use `;` between dbname & host

Comment: `myDB` !== `myDBname`

Comment: A Life Pro Tip: to avoid a frustration, always read the error message. One saying `"Unknown database 'myDBName,host=localhost'"` is exceptionally suggestive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.`;` instead of `,` needed between dbname and host

2.Also  database name is not correct (it need to be `myDB`) As you said that `$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","myusername","mypass","myDB")` is working fine.

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=myDB;host=localhost","mysusername","mypass",array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

The error is gone and I am able to connect to the db now.

For the record, this is the first time I saw semi-colon instead of comma from all the examples I saw online including the ones I saw here.

Comment: @Tairoc  glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

> In general, a DSN consists of the PDO driver name, followed by a colon, followed by the PDO driver-specific connection syntax.

You should use a `semi-colon` not a `comma`.
It would be like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=myDB;host=localhost","mysusername","mypass",array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
```

Comment: This answer didn't deserve a downvote. Edit: nor another which I can honestly say is not mine.

Comment: @Fred-ii- in fact my intention and focus was on the main problem which was the `Exception` he was facing with. I dont see any point for downvoting and nor I understand insight of person who downvoted me :|